# Custom plugin - show popup before element save

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I've got a plugin that's got element types. I've got a `Transaction` element that I need the user to confirm before saving.

I've tried to use the jQuery that comes with craft:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var txt;
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save?")) {
      txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
      txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
      return false;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

    console.log(txt);
  })
```

but the element still saves on the edit page.

How can I prevent the element from saving if the user clicks cancel.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that Craft has its attached its own `submit` handler to the form already, and jQuery event listeners are always triggered in the order  they were attached.

You could verify that by doing a `$('form').off('submit')` (which, in theory, should de-register any existing event listeners for the `'submit'` event) - i.e.

```js
$('form').off('submit');
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    ...
});
```

I don't think de-registering Craft's own event listeners is the best idea, though.

You might have more luck hi-jacking the form's submit button instead of the actual form, i.e. something like this (untested):

```js
$('form').on('button[type="submit"]', 'click', function (e) {
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save?')) {
       return true;
   }
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

If that works, you should be almost there – although you'd probably have to hi-jack the form save shortcut as well (i.e. Cmd+S and whatever the Windows equivalent is).